# Can the caller not pass the extra arguments to a variadic function in C?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a variadic function:

```
        void            some_func(
        char            arg1,
        int             arg2,
        char            arg3,
        char            arg4,
        int             arg5,
        char            arg6, ...
        ) 
        {
        /* Do some stuff */
        }
```

Can I have function calls like the below:

1. `some_func('a', 23, 'c', 'd', 56, 'y', "yahoo"); /* yahoo is extra, but valid */`
2. `some_func('a', 23, 'c', 'd', 56, 'y'); /* Nothing extra passed, only 6 args, is this allowed??? */`

My concern is point2. Can we **not** have the extra arguments in the call if the function is variadic?

Answer (score 3):

> Can we not have the extra arguments in the call if the function is variadic

Yes, that is the whole point of a variadic function.  Any arguments explicitly defined must be given, but any number or type of additional arguments may be passed, including 0.

Section 6.7.6.3p9 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding function declarations states:

> If the list terminates with an ellipsis ( `, ...`), no information
> about the number or types of the parameters after the comma is
> supplied.

Given that "no information about the number ... of the parameters after the comma is supplied", that does not preclude 0 additional arguments being passed.

Comment: yes, but 6.7.6.3p9 does not explicitly state that zero is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. For example good old `int printf(const char * restrict fmt, ...)` works this way.

```
printf("Hello world\n");
```

-- EDIT --

I was not able to find any wording explicitly allowing zero variadic arguments. The best reference I found is an example at [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p19](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p19)

> EXAMPLE 3 The declaration
> `int (*fpfi(int (*)(long), int))(int, ...);`
> declares a function fpfi that returns a pointer to a function returning an int. The function fpfi has two parameters: a pointer to a function returning an int (with one parameter of type long int), and an int. The pointer returned by fpfi points to a function that has one int parameter and accepts **zero or more additional arguments** of any type.

Note that the examples are not normative.